# jqGrid - stop running this script or unresponsive script prompts

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

Using jQuery 1.9.1 and jqGrid 4.5.2 to display data from a table.  I cannot use ASP.NET or PHP.  I'm using date & time controls to limit data selection to a maximum of 90 days from the table.  I'm also using dropdowns to filter the data, but using them are optional.

The average number of rows written to the table is around 2000 per day (in a 5 day work week).

In testing using the grid defined below, I pulled around 2500 rows into the grid.  IE8 prompted me about a half-dozen times with messages to "Stop running this script" and Firefox also gave me "Unresponsive script" prompts.  Sorting performance is similar.

I'm not doing any edits to the data in the grid, only displaying it.  The main reason I have all the rows showing at once is in order to allow a user to copy the contents of the grid & paste it into an Excel workbook.

The grid code is as follows:

```
$("#histGrid").jqGrid({
    url: vhistURL,
    datatype: "xml",
        mtype: "GET",
    colNames: ["ID","SystemID", "Display", "Short Msg","Date/Time", "Historical Msg"],
        colModel:[
        {name:"HistID",
        index:"HistID",
        hidden: true,
        width:10,
        align:"left",
        sorttype:"int",
        xmlmap:"Rowset>Row>HistID"
        },
        {name:"MachineID",
        index:"MachineID",
        width:23,
        align:"center", 
        sorttype:"int",
        xmlmap:"Rowset>Row>MachineID"
        },
        {name:"DisplayName",
        index:"DisplayName",
        width:52,
        align:"left",
        sorttype:"text",
        xmlmap:"Rowset>Row>DisplayName"
        },
        {name:"MsgText",
        index:"MsgText",
        width: 150,
        align:"left",
        sorttype:"text",
        xmlmap:"Rowset>Row>MsgText"
        },
        {name:"HistDateTime",
        index:"HistDateTime",
        width:60,
        align:"center",
        formatter:"date",
        formatoptions: {"srcformat":"ISO8601Long", "newformat":"m/d/Y H:i"},
        sorttype:"date",
        xmlmap:"Rowset>Row>HistDateTime"
        },
        {name:"HistMessage",
        index:"HistMessage",
        width:200,
        align:"left",
        sorttype:"text",
        xmlmap:"Rowset>Row>HistMessage"
        }
        ],
    rowNum: 100000,                 
    pager: jQuery("#pager1"),
    sortname:"HistID",
    sortorder: "asc",
    viewrecords: true,
    gridview: true,
    width: gridwidth,
    autoencode: true,
    loadonce: true,
    height: "100%",
    toolbar: [true, "top"],
    hidegrid: false,                // hides the ability to collapse grid
    defaults: {
        altrows: true, 
        recordtext: "View {0} - {1} of {2}",
        emptyrecords:  "No records to view",
        pgtext: "Page  {0} of {1}"
        },
    xmlReader:  { 
        root: "Rowsets", 
                row: "Row",
        repeatitems: false,
        id: "HistID"
        },
    loadComplete: function() { 
        // bold the column headers
        $("th.ui-th-column").css("font-size","1.25em");
        $("th.ui-th-column").css("font-weight","bold");
        $("td",".jqgrow").css("font-size","1.15em");
        }
    });
```

I have taken the option to stop running the script once, and IE8 takes me into the `loadComplete` portion of the code (the last row).

Like I said, it's not doing much more than grabbing the data & sorting, but the performance is terrible.

What can I do to be able to display a relatively large number of rows in jqGrid?  Any performance items in my code I need to address?

Comment: first would remove inline style calls and use CSS. That's a lot of elements to update there!! Would try using json instead of xml too. Likely more performant

Comment: how can any user need 100000 rows on display? What a visual overload, and browser overload too

Comment: @charlietfl - I will try the CSS instead of the inline styling. Unfortunately, XML is the only way I'm able to receive the data.

Comment: @charlietfl - the CSS does make a difference, but it now prompts once or twice instead of 6 times when loading.  Is there a better way to gauge what the # of rows in my grid setting ought to be?  Is there a way - other than having the whole grid displayed - to allow the user to copy the contents of it & paste into Excel?

Comment: if was me would export to excel from server, let user download and do what they need with it